# PHP: How to export a file to a different directory?

Tags: php, download, desktop

I'm new to php and I'm trying to figure out how to export my file to a different directory. So far I have..

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Content-Disposition attachment; filename=\"test.text\"");
```

I export my file, but they all go to *Downloads*, how can I make it go to my /Desktop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can't change that with code. You need to change that setting in your browser.

Comment: really... I'm building a script that would export a file that needs to be dropped into my project folder, you're saying I have to go into "Downloads" each time and move it?

Comment: I can change it in my browser, but I wouldn't want other random downloads to go in there when it doesn't belong there...:(

Comment: server doesn't have access to client folders for security reasons. this is a setting in your browser.  if you are using chrome or firefox, change settings to make it ask you where to download.